# Questions about example Hartshorne III.9.7.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne III.9.7.1 page 258 the author consider a curve $Y$ with a node and $f:X\to Y$ its normalization. He wants to prove that this map is not flat. He reasons as follow:

- If it were, then $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ would be a flat sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module: ok cf [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596360/example-9-7-1-in-hartshorne)
- **problem 1**: It is coherent: why we don't have in general $f_*($coherent$)=$coherent
- Hence it is locally free: ok (finit type+local+flat+noetherian)
- **Problem 2**: $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ has rank 1: why? in ring I guess that is to say $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$ has rank 1 as $A_\mathfrak{p}$-module that is (isn't?) that $B_\mathfrak{q}\otimes k(\mathfrak{p})$ is a dimension 1 $k(\mathfrak{p})$-vectorial space: it is always unclear to me.
- Hence $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is an invertible sheaf: ok, by definition.
- **Problem 3**: There are 2 points $P_1$, $P_2$ going to the node $Q$ of $Y$: why? In exercise I.5.6 it's proven but when $X$ is the blowing-up. Maybe for curves one has blowing-up=normalization?
- **Problem 4**: Hence $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_Q$ has two generators as $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module: why?
- **Problem 5**: Hence $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_Q$ is not locally free: why? Does the author make a mistake and he means that it's not an invertible sheaf?

  Thanks for all your answers, even if there are partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Coherent has a finiteness assumption which can be fail very easily. Consider the natural projection $\pi:\Bbb A^1_k\to \operatorname{Spec} k$. Then $\pi_*(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^1_k})$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space which is not coherent.
2. The rank of $\mathcal{F}$ at a point $x\in X$ is $\dim_{k(x)} \mathcal{F}_x\otimes k(x)$, and when we talk about rank of a sheaf, we usually mean at the generic point. Since there is a neighborhood of the generic point where normalization is an isomorphism, we see that the rank of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is 1.
3. A normal variety is singular in codimension two, which means that a normal curve is smooth. The same method you used to show that the (proper, birational) blowdown map from a smooth curve to your node has two points in the fiber over the node should work here.
4. Consider the indicator functions of the distinct points in the fiber (the function which is $1$ on that point and $0$ on the other point of the fiber). There's no $\mathcal{O}_Y$ relation between them (no function on $Y$ can tell the two points apart since they both map to the same point of $Y$), so they have to be independent.
5. In a line bundle, any stalk of a nonvanishing section should be a generator of the stalk, so there should be an $\mathcal{O}_Y$ relation between the two sections. This contradicts 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A few precisions:

Comment: 1) Finally why $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent?

2) Ok I have to take care of finding this isomorphism

3) Ok I return to this exercise

4) Ok I take $f_1\in\mathfrak{m}_{P_1}(f_*(\mathcal{O}_X))_{\mathfrak{m}_Q}$ and not in $\mathfrak{m}_{P_2}(f_*(\mathcal{O}_X))_{\mathfrak{m}_Q}$ and vis-versa.

5) Hence contradiction is with the rank 1 aspect?

Comment: @Macadam 1. Normalization is finite for a curve over a field. It's an easy fact that the pushforwards of a coherent sheaf along a finite map is again coherent. 5. Sure? The statements in conflict are "the stalk at $Q$ has two generators" and "any stalk of any line bundle has one generator".

Comment: I wonder if it's also possible to argue as follows: Choose affine open sets $V \subseteq Y$ where $f_* O_X$ is free, and $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$. Then, since $f_* O_X$ is free of rank 1, $f$ is an isomorphism between $U$ and $V$, contradicting that it sends 2 points to 1 point. Although I'm not sure if restriction to affine opens commutes with pushforward like that. I think we need to also add in Stacks project Lemma 29.54.3, which states $f$ is affine.

Comment: @DavidLui no, because $f_*O_X$ is locally free on the complement of the node and the map is an isomorphism there. (You've correctly identified that the rest of your argument needs some help - here's how I'd phrase the thing you're trying to do there, which again, doesn't really work for the reasons indicated above: "since normalization is affine, the preimage of the affine open set $V\subset Y$ is an affine open $U\subset X$.")